# He cambiado a php7 y estoy teniendo problemas con las consultas a la bd

Tags: php7

He modificado una consulta y me da error en el código, cosa que con la version 5.6 de php no me hacía os dejo el código.

```
$limite = time()-5*60;
$sql_del_visitantes = "delete from visitantes where fecha < ?";
$consulta_visitantes = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql_del_visitantes);
$ok_visitantes = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta_visitantes, 'i', $limite);
$total_ip = mysqli_num_rows($consulta_visitantes);
```

El error me lo da en mysqli_num_rows.
Pense que lo habia solucionado

```
$sql_del_visitantes = "delete from visitantes where fecha < ?";
$consulta_del_visitantes = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql_del_visitantes);
$ok_del_visitantes = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta_del_visitantes, 'i', $limite);

$sql_visit = "select ip from visitantes where ip = ?"; 
$consulta_visit = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql_visit);
$ok_visit = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta_visit, 's', $ip);
$total_ip = mysqli_num_rows($consulta_visit);
```

Pero mi gozo en un pozo, sigue el error en mysqli_num_rows

Comment: Hola! Cuál es el error? Por favor edita tu pregunta y añádelo.

Comment: Tienes que ejecutar la consulta preparada y las consultas del tipo `DELETE` no arrojan `num_rows` sino `affected_rows`. Revisa la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

No estás ejecutando la consulta, es decir, te falta `mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta_visit);` después de `$ok_visit = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta_visit, 's', $ip);`.

[Mira la documentación aquí.](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Gracias, solucionado